# Aptana intermiittent unable to close output stream

Tags: php, macos, ftp, aptana

Hope someone can help with this as it's driving me mad! I'm using Aptana 3.1 on OS X Lion but had the same problem with the previous build of Aptana and Snow Leopard.

I have several ftp connections set up and get an intermittent problem when trying to upload files. It seems to happen much more often with larger php files but not all the time. I click the 'up' arrow to upload a file to the server and the upload progress bar gets to 100% then hangs for about a minute, I then get a message saying 'error unable to close output stream' with the option to continue or cancel.

This is the corresponding entry in the error log:

```
!SUBENTRY 1 com.aptana.core.io 4 0 2012-02-01 09:51:22.863
!MESSAGE Unable to close output stream.
!STACK 0
com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.ControlChannelIOException: Read timed out
at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPControlSocket.e(FTPControlSocket.java:1041)
at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPControlSocket.b(FTPControlSocket.java:1076)  
at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.validateTransfer(FTPClient.java:2545)
at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPOutputStream.close(FTPOutputStream.java:275)
at com.aptana.filesystem.ftp.internal.FTPFileUploadOutputStream.close(FTPFileUploadOutputStream.java:106)
at com.aptana.core.io.efs.SyncUtils.safeClose(SyncUtils.java:165)
at com.aptana.core.io.efs.SyncUtils.copy(SyncUtils.java:116)
at com.aptana.ide.syncing.core.old.Synchronizer.uploadAndDelete(Synchronizer.java:1370)
at com.aptana.ide.syncing.core.old.Synchronizer.upload(Synchronizer.java:1274)
at com.aptana.ide.syncing.ui.actions.UploadAction$1.run(UploadAction.java:128)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

I've tried deleting the connection and recreating with it. I'm using passive mode on port 21.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks,

Derek

Comment: This isn't caused by Aptana, it seems to be a problem with the host. Happens to me with multiple hosts running different flavors of Linux, regardless of the program used to upload. It usually resolves itself eventually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also if this fails, this message is shown when there is no free space in the server.

Comment: If you have UNIX server, you can check for the available disk space with `df -h`. To check the size of a particular directory and see if it's a space hog, you can use `du -sh some-directory-name`.

Answer (score 3):

OK Fixed it. Emptying Aptana's error log seems to have done it!

Help -> Aptana -> Clear log file

Comment: Half-worked for me. In some circumstances it still reports the error.

Comment: Wow, this just helped me so much. In my case, Aptana wasn't releasing the FTP connections so the server was locking me out due to too many open connections from my IP address. Clearing the log file resolved the issue entirely. Thanks.