# Aptana Studio - Unable to close output stream

Tags: ftp, aptana

I'm using Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.4.0.201304151603 and am uploading files to a cPanel Linux hosting server via the Aptana built in publish to FTP facility.

Every few times I upload a file, say every five times or so, the upload process is hanging and 30 seconds later Aptana prompts "Unable to close the output stream" before giving up.  The file is not uploaded.

I've tried clearing the Aptana log file as suggested in another post, and have worked with two clean installs of Aptana on two clean installs of Windows.  The project I am working on is also connected to GitHub.

See below an extract of the FTP Console log - firstly a normal and successful upload, followed by an example of this problem.

Thanks for your help,
Richard

```
---------- RECONNECTING - FTP staging.tewllr.org ----------
220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
220-You are user number 1 of 50 allowed.
220-Local time is now 12:56. Server port: 21.
220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
ftp> USER staginge
331 User staginge OK. Password required
ftp> PASS ********
230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
ftp> PWD
257 "/" is your current location
ftp> TYPE I
200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
ftp> NOOP
200 Zzz...
ftp> TYPE I
200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
ftp> STAT /public_html/assets/css/lib/
213-STAT
drwxr-xr-x    2 staginge   staginge         4096 May 31 12:56 .
drwxr-xr-x    2 staginge   staginge         4096 May 31 12:56 ..
-rwxr-xr-x    1 staginge   staginge         1783 May 23 18:02 base.css
-rwxr-xr-x    1 staginge   staginge         4046 May  3 20:09 bookings.css
-rwxr-xr-x    1 staginge   staginge         6355 May 23 17:55 buttons.css
-rwxr-xr-x    1 staginge   staginge         9308 Oct 26  2012 csshover3.htc
-rw-r--r--    1 staginge   staginge        18577 May 30 20:16 events.css
-rwxr-xr-x    1 staginge   staginge        31265 May 30 22:20 features.css
-rw-r--r--    1 staginge   staginge        31265 May 31 12:56 features.css._tmp_uploadcss
-rwxr-xr-x    1 staginge   staginge        13000 May 31 10:00 forms.css
-rwxr-xr-x    1 staginge   staginge          858 May 20 10:11 ie-patch.css
-rwxr-xr-x    1 staginge   staginge         3823 Apr 30 18:28 lists.css
-rwxr-xr-x    1 staginge   staginge         8440 May 22 14:18 menu.css
-rwxr-xr-x    1 staginge   staginge         4682 Feb 20 17:06 plugins.css
-rwxr-xr-x    1 staginge   staginge         4241 May 23 23:46 products.css
-rwxr-xr-x    1 staginge   staginge            0 Jan 16 22:34 skype.css
-rwxr-xr-x    1 staginge   staginge         4923 May 22 14:26 template.css
213 End.
ftp> TYPE I
200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
ftp> CWD /public_html/assets/css/lib
250 OK. Current directory is /public_html/assets/css/lib
ftp> PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (195,8,196,197,113,50).
ftp> STOR features.css._tmp_uploadcss
150 Accepted data connection
226-File successfully transferred
226 0.325 seconds (measured here), 93.92 Kbytes per second
ftp> SIZE features.css
213 31265
ftp> DELE features.css
250 Deleted features.css
ftp> RNFR features.css._tmp_uploadcss
350 RNFR accepted - file exists, ready for destination
ftp> RNTO features.css
250 File successfully renamed or moved
ftp> SITE CHMOD 755 features.css
200 Permissions changed on features.css
ftp> CWD /public_html/assets/css/lib
250 OK. Current directory is /public_html/assets/css/lib
ftp> MFMT 20130531115253 features.css
213 UTIME OK
ftp> QUIT
221-Goodbye. You uploaded 0 and downloaded 0 kbytes.
221 Logout.
ftp> QUIT
221-Goodbye. You uploaded 31 and downloaded 0 kbytes.
221 Logout.
---------- RECONNECTING - FTP staging.tewllr.org ----------
220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
220-You are user number 1 of 50 allowed.
220-Local time is now 12:57. Server port: 21.
220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
ftp> USER staginge
331 User staginge OK. Password required
ftp> PASS ********
230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
ftp> PWD
257 "/" is your current location
ftp> TYPE I
200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
ftp> NOOP
200 Zzz...
ftp> TYPE I
200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
ftp> STAT /
213-STAT
drwx--x--x   14 staginge   staginge         4096 May 29 10:48 .
drwx--x--x   14 staginge   staginge         4096 May 29 10:48 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 staginge   staginge           33 Aug 27  2012 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--    1 staginge   staginge          176 Aug 27  2012 .bash_profile
-rw-r--r--    1 staginge   staginge          124 Aug 27  2012 .bashrc
-rw-rw-rw-    1 staginge   staginge          174 Aug 27  2012 .buildpath
-rw-------    1 staginge   staginge           17 Aug 27  2012 .contactemail
drwx------    5 staginge   staginge         4096 May 31 09:59 .cpanel
-rw-------    1 staginge   staginge           16 May 10 04:22 .ftpquota
-rw-rw-rw-    1 staginge   staginge           13 Aug 27  2012 .gitignore
drwxr-x---    3 staginge   99               4096 Aug 30  2012 .htpasswds
-rw-------    1 staginge   staginge           12 May 29 10:48 .lastlogin
-rw-rw-rw-    1 staginge   staginge          560 Aug 27  2012 .project
drwx------    2 staginge   staginge         4096 Sep  3  2012 .trash
-rw-rw-rw-    1 staginge   staginge           56 Aug 27  2012 README
drwxr-xr-x   12 staginge   staginge         4096 Sep  6  2012 ZendFramework-1.12.0
drwxr-xr-x    3 staginge   staginge         4096 May 16 16:35 __legacy_resources
lrwxrwxrwx    1 staginge   staginge           34 Aug 27  2012 access-logs -> /usr/local/apache/domlogs/staginge
drwxr-x---    3 staginge   12               4096 May 24 15:26 etc
drwxr-xr-x    3 staginge   staginge         4096 Sep 27  2012 import_data
drwxr-x--x   10 staginge   staginge         4096 May  2 15:35 mail
drwxr-xr-x    3 staginge   staginge         4096 Aug 27  2012 public_ftp
drwxr-x---   25 staginge   99               4096 May 30 23:06 public_html
drwxr-xr-x    4 staginge   staginge         4096 Oct  4  2012 servio
-rw-r--r--    1 staginge   staginge      1589812 May 31 00:41 servio_daily.log
-rw-r--r--    1 staginge   staginge            0 May 31 12:30 servio_failover.log
-rw-r--r--    1 staginge   staginge         2800 May 31 12:01 servio_hourly.log
-rw-r--r--    1 staginge   staginge         1681 May 31 12:56 servio_minute.log
-rw-r--r--    1 staginge   staginge          134 May 26 00:00 servio_weekly.log
drwxr-xr-x    8 staginge   staginge         4096 May  2 15:35 tmp
lrwxrwxrwx    1 staginge   staginge           11 Aug 27  2012 www -> public_html
213 End.
ftp> STAT /public_html/
213-STAT
drwxr-x---   25 staginge   99               4096 May 30 23:06 .
drwxr-x---   25 staginge   99               4096 May 30 23:06 ..
-rw-rw-rw-    1 staginge   staginge         1217 May 21 12:07 .htaccess
-rw-rw-rw-    1 staginge   staginge           80 Oct 26  2012 404.html
drwxr-xr-x   24 staginge   staginge         4096 May 29 21:31 admin
drwxr-xr-x    7 staginge   staginge         4096 Oct 31  2012 assets
drwxr-xr-x   10 staginge   staginge         4096 May 25 00:04 au
drwxr-xr-x   10 staginge   staginge         4096 May 30 20:48 ca
drwxr-xr-x   10 staginge   staginge         4096 May 21 12:19 cee
drwxr-xr-x    2 staginge   staginge         4096 Aug 27  2012 cgi-bin
drwxr-xr-x    2 staginge   staginge         4096 May 21 17:20 co
drwxr-xr-x    2 staginge   staginge         4096 May 21 10:09 de
-rw-r--r--    1 staginge   staginge         1406 Sep  1  2012 favicon.ico
drwxr-xr-x    2 staginge   staginge         4096 May 21 14:18 fr
drwxr-xr-x    2 staginge   staginge         4096 May 21 14:21 hu
drwxr-xr-x   10 staginge   staginge         4096 May 20 23:21 in
-rw-r--r--    1 staginge   staginge         1479 May 22 15:35 index.html
-rw-r--r--    1 staginge   staginge           25 Sep  1  2012 info.php
drwxr-xr-x    2 staginge   staginge         4096 May 21 14:14 my
drwxr-xr-x    3 staginge   staginge         4096 May 28 10:22 myrepono
drwxr-xr-x    2 staginge   staginge         4096 May 21 16:55 nl
drwxr-xr-x    2 staginge   staginge         4096 May 21 16:55 nl-en
drwxr-xr-x    2 staginge   staginge         4096 May 21 14:23 no
drwxr-xr-x   10 staginge   staginge         4096 May 21 12:25 nz
drwxr-xr-x    2 staginge   staginge         4096 May 21 17:20 se
drwxr-xr-x    4 staginge   staginge         4096 May  9 19:07 secure
-rw-r--r--    1 staginge   staginge          447 Oct 23  2012 servio.php
-rw-r--r--    1 staginge   staginge          347 Oct 23  2012 settings.servio.inc.php
drwxr-xr-x   10 staginge   staginge         4096 May 20 23:11 sg
-rw-r--r--    1 staginge   staginge          225 Oct  5  2012 sitemap.html
-rw-r--r--    1 staginge   staginge      3468696 May 31 00:01 sitemap.xml
drwxr-xr-x   10 staginge   staginge         4096 May 30 23:07 uk
drwxr-xr-x   10 staginge   staginge         4096 May 30 20:37 usa
drwxr-xr-x   10 staginge   staginge         4096 May 20 22:26 za
213 End.
ftp> STAT /public_html/assets/
213-STAT
drwxr-xr-x    7 staginge   staginge         4096 Oct 31  2012 .
drwxr-xr-x    7 staginge   staginge         4096 Oct 31  2012 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 staginge   staginge           18 Oct 30  2012 .htaccess
drwxr-xr-x    3 staginge   staginge         4096 May 31 12:35 css
drwxr-xr-x    3 staginge   staginge         4096 May 27 11:00 dl
drwxr-xr-x   15 staginge   staginge         4096 Mar 19 18:05 img
drwxr-xr-x    3 staginge   staginge         4096 May 31 12:52 js
drwxr-xr-x   13 staginge   staginge         4096 May 23 23:11 plugins
213 End.
ftp> STAT /public_html/assets/css/
213-STAT
drwxr-xr-x    3 staginge   staginge         4096 May 31 12:35 .
drwxr-xr-x    3 staginge   staginge         4096 May 31 12:35 ..
-rwxr-xr-x    1 staginge   staginge         9865 Feb 12 16:27 backend.css
-rwxr-xr-x    1 staginge   staginge          175 Apr 24 21:38 bookings-wizard.css
-rwxr-xr-x    1 staginge   staginge          513 Oct 29  2012 editor-course.css
-rwxr-xr-x    1 staginge   staginge          283 Oct 26  2012 editor-standard.css
-rwxr-xr-x    1 staginge   staginge          182 Oct 26  2012 frontend-template.css
-rwxr-xr-x    1 staginge   staginge        13180 May 31 12:32 frontend.css
-rwxr-xr-x    1 staginge   staginge         1608 Oct 26  2012 frontpage.css
-rwxr-xr-x    1 staginge   staginge         2373 Feb 26 18:25 iframe.css
drwxr-xr-x    2 staginge   staginge         4096 May 31 12:56 lib
213 End.
ftp> STAT /public_html/assets/css/lib/
213-STAT
drwxr-xr-x    2 staginge   staginge         4096 May 31 12:56 .
drwxr-xr-x    2 staginge   staginge         4096 May 31 12:56 ..
-rwxr-xr-x    1 staginge   staginge         1783 May 23 18:02 base.css
-rwxr-xr-x    1 staginge   staginge         4046 May  3 20:09 bookings.css
-rwxr-xr-x    1 staginge   staginge         6355 May 23 17:55 buttons.css
-rwxr-xr-x    1 staginge   staginge         9308 Oct 26  2012 csshover3.htc
-rw-r--r--    1 staginge   staginge        18577 May 30 20:16 events.css
-rwxr-xr-x    1 staginge   staginge        31265 May 31 12:52 features.css
-rwxr-xr-x    1 staginge   staginge        13000 May 31 10:00 forms.css
-rwxr-xr-x    1 staginge   staginge          858 May 20 10:11 ie-patch.css
-rwxr-xr-x    1 staginge   staginge         3823 Apr 30 18:28 lists.css
-rwxr-xr-x    1 staginge   staginge         8440 May 22 14:18 menu.css
-rwxr-xr-x    1 staginge   staginge         4682 Feb 20 17:06 plugins.css
-rwxr-xr-x    1 staginge   staginge         4241 May 23 23:46 products.css
-rwxr-xr-x    1 staginge   staginge            0 Jan 16 22:34 skype.css
-rwxr-xr-x    1 staginge   staginge         4923 May 22 14:26 template.css
213 End.
ftp> TYPE I
200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
ftp> CWD /public_html/assets/css/lib
250 OK. Current directory is /public_html/assets/css/lib
ftp> PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (195,8,196,197,222,3).
ftp> STOR features.css._tmp_uploadcss
150 Accepted data connection
ftp> QUIT
221-Goodbye. You uploaded 0 and downloaded 0 kbytes.
221 Logout.
ftp> QUIT
226-File successfully transferred
226 0.328 seconds (measured here), 93.00 Kbytes per second
```

Comment: Have you tried these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9094010/aptana-intermiittent-unable-to-close-output-stream?rq=1

Comment: Yes; there is plenty of space on the server and as I've said I've already tried clearing Aptana's log file.

Comment: Are you having these same issues with another FTP client like Filezilla? If you have tried on two clean installs, it could be a server problem. Is it possible your connection is intermittent? Using wireless or a bad cord?